# Magento custom option not displaying after reindex

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I have a magento store in which the "custom option" disappear after reindexing, it doesn't seem to matter which cache I index however after the indexing has started or completed the "Custom Options" view on the front end will disappear. The only way to re-enable the custom options is to resave the options from the back-end. It seems to work for some items if I have the requirement set to "no", however this does not work for other questions.

Store is running version 1.6.2.0, using the default theme and nothing obvious is showing up in the error log(s)

Any troubleshooting advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I've also tried clearing cache before and after the indexing, but it still happens.

Comment: Probably some third part modules are creating that issue. Are there any modules besides the core?

Comment: There are a few other mods, i'll check tomorrow what they where

Answer (score 1):

try this - goto manage products - select the product you are having problems with. Under the tab labeled "Design" goto "Display Product Options In" and change the value to "product Info Column"